# Why are my sidebars being styled differently in template override?

Tags: templates, css, template-override

I have two template overrides set up. One so I can display this page differently from other pages:

http://pfp-consortium.org/index.php/activities/defense-education-enhancement-program-deep

And another so I can display my event related pages differently:

https://pfp-consortium.org/index.php/events

On the first one, the sidebars are styled as they are on other pages. But on the event page, the styling goes away.

In firebug, the breakdown seems to happen at this point:

```
<div class="rt-block featured-block">
```

Prior to that point, everything appears identical in firebug. On the first override, clicking on that div indicates my gantry-custom.css is being applied. But when I inspect the same div in firebug for the event page, it does not show gantry-custom.css being applied.

I am at a loss for what could be happening here.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not identical. There is a small difference between both pages:

Take a look at the `div` with the id `rt-sidebar-a`. In your first page its placed in a container with classes `rt-grid-3 rt-pull-6` and in the second page the parent container has the classes `rt-grid-2 rt-pull-8`.

Your CSS rule for styling this left sidebar is `#rt-main .rt-grid-3 .rt-block` which is the answer why this rule is applied to the first page and not to the second.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to figure out the simplest CSS selector that would apply to both .rt-grid-2 and rt-grid-3. Selectors like #rt-main .rt-grid-3 .rt-grid-2 wouldn't work, what I am looking for is the equivalent of "select elements that come from either of these classes". I suppose statements such as #rt-main .rt-grid-3 .rt-block, #rt-main .rt-grid-2 .rt-block { Is that considered clean code?

Comment: I think that is absolutely valid code